# Error: name":"Invariant Violation","framesToPop":1

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

I'm seeing this strange error.
I'm writing an app which uses the graph api to retrieve event details from facebook.
The event has a couple of attributes from which:
 - owner which is an object containing owner id, owner name, and other attributes
 - cover which is an object representing the event cover image details.

I save events in a mongo database, here is what my event model looks like:

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  name: String,
  _id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    default: shortid.generate,
  },
  start_time: Date,
  end_time: Date,
  description: String,
  owner: {},
  cover: {},
  venue: {},
  privacy: String,
  timezone: String,
  location: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  event_type: {},
});
```

I have an express route which sends back a given event by id:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Event.findById(req.params.id).exec((error, events) => {
    if (error){
      res.json(error);
    }
    res.json(events);
  })
});
```

My component architecture goes like this:

-EventPage component which contains an EventDetails component.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios';
import EventDetails from './eventDetails';

class EventPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      event: {},
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(`/api/events/${this.props.params.id}`)
      .then((eventResponse) => {
        this.setState({
          event: eventResponse.data
        })
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <EventDetails event={this.state.event} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

EventPage.propTypes = {
};

export default EventPage;




import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import _ from 'lodash';

class EventDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { name, description, start_time, end_time, owner } = this.props.event;
    return(
      <div className='row'>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
          <p>{JSON.stringify(this.props.event)}</p>
          <p>{this.props.event.owner}</p>
        <pre>

        </pre>


      </div>
    )
  }
}

EventDetails.propTypes = {
};

export default EventDetails;
```

Trying to display the event owner's name results in this error:

{"name":"Invariant Violation","framesToPop":1}

The error comes from the axios error handler in the EventPage component.

Anyone sees what I've done wrong here?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I had probably the same problem with {"name":"Invariant Violation","framesToPop":1}.

I've passed a javascript object instead of an array and it worked for me.

```
    Message.find({}).sort({'date': -1}).limit(50).exec().then( (doc, err) => {
        console.log('found');
        const messages = [];
        doc.map( (item) => {
            messages.push({data: item});
        });
        callback(err, {items: messages}); 
    });
```